# Kernel log flooded with "read cpu" lines

Tags: kernel, logging

On my newly setup system 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64), the syslog is flooded with cryptic kernel `read cpu` messages.

What is the reason for this and how can this be turned off?

```
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574630] sysctl_ibrs_enabled = 0, sysctl_ibpb_enabled = 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574633] use_ibrs = 4, use_ibpb = 4
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574634] read cpu 0 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574635] read cpu 1 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574636] read cpu 2 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574637] read cpu 3 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574638] read cpu 4 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574639] read cpu 5 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574639] read cpu 6 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574640] read cpu 7 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574641] read cpu 8 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574642] read cpu 9 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574643] read cpu 10 ibrs val 0
Feb 14 09:43:55 kernel: [  987.574644] read cpu 11 ibrs val 0
```

Comment: I'm not an export at all, but if I understood well, IBRS (Indirect Branch Restricted Speculation) seems to be one of the latest Intel microcode update that is supposed to limit the Meldown attack : https://lwn.net/Articles/743019/ . Did you update your microcode (yourself, or via a Windows update) ?

Comment: This is a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.3 box, with the latest kernel and all upgrades applied via `apt update && apt upgrade -y`

Comment: Can you try to run `sudo -i` and then `cat /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled` (report the output) and finally `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled` (tell me if it's still spawning the message)

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled` gives me `0`. So this is probably not it.

Comment: And if you try to change it to 1 or 2 (it will enable ibrs), does it change something?

Comment: @tobiasBora Sure I can give it a try, but could you tell my why I would want to change that setting?

Comment: Well in the link I gave you, they explain that this command is used to enable/disable IBRS at run time. And because I don't know what cause this message, I try to see if it could come from the fact that IBRS is disabled on your system. These modifications should be only for current session anyway, so it shouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73129/discussion-between-thomas-and-tobiasbora).

Comment: The chat is gone now - did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a launchpad bug on this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1755627

There's a good chance it will be fixed soon.